# Is there a cross browser way of styling scrollbars?

Tags: css, cross-browser, scrollbar

pseudo-classes is limited to webkit
http://caniuse.com/#search=scrollbar

What is the current best approach?

Comment: jScrollPane? :)

Comment: From the page you linked, "Currently scrollbar styling doesn't appear to be on any standards track.". It's unlikely to become a standard for a while (if ever), so there probably isn't a way that will work for *every* browser. (although, by usage ~85% of browsers support it)